Find out most recently used command (regardless of terminal input)
I previously asked this question about cycling through recently used tabs, and nobody could come up (yet) with something like I was looking for. However, I found that basically all the ingredients to define it are already in Emacs, so I decided to program my own. The only question is how to make it that,

if the command is used several times in a row, it goes to the next tab in the list of most recent tabs,

but if another command is used in-between, it starts all the way at the beginning of that list.


So I thought I should just check which command was used most recently, but I don't know how. I already found command-history, but that variable only records commands for which the terminal was used, while I need to find the most recent command regardless of whether it used the terminal. There has to be a way to do that, right?

But tabs are necessarily terminal-local, no?  (The tab-bar is connected to a frame, and the tab-line to a window-of-a-frame).  last-command is the terminal-local previous command.

Yeah, but command-history only records commands that read arguments from the terminal. I should have formulated this more clearly. Anyway, last-command does what I want. Thanks!

Please post that answer (last-command) or delete the question. Thx.

C-hv last-command contains the (terminal-local) previous command.
